# How to load google's android places api in your current location

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am starting to learn places api.  I managed to create an activity and when you click the button renders the places api location picker with a map.   My problem is I can do this with a hardcoded LatLangBounds, what I want is when I render the map is to start on my current location.  I have done this using maps api but for this places api I am confused.

```
private static final int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
private TextView mName;
private TextView mAddress;
private TextView mAttributions;
private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_HARD_CODED_LOCATION = new LatLngBounds(
        new LatLng(37.398160, -122.180831), new LatLng(37.430610, -121.972090));

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_picker);

    /**
     * not part of places api standard code to add back function to action bar
     */
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    mAttributions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    Button pickerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickerButton);
    pickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder =
                        new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
                intentBuilder.setLatLngBounds(BOUNDS_HARD_CODED_LOCATION );
                Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(PlacePickerActivity.this);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);

            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException
                    | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can obtain your current position using the `Location Services`. When you have the position, you can take the `VisibleRegion` of the camera map, using the method `onCameraChange()` from the maps API. Now with the visible region object you can construct new `LatLngBounds` with your current position and call the `Places API`